# Почему абсолютно позиционированный элемент накладывается на один и тот же элемент? Как это убрать?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Первый элемент абсолютно позиционированный, второй – нет. Я задаю второму элементу верхний марджин, который равен высоте абсолютно позиционированного элемента для того, чтобы "обычный" элемент поместить под абсолютно позиционированным. Но вместо того, чтобы остаться вверху, абсолютно позиционированный элемент сдвигается вместе с "обычным" элементом.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(4, 127, 214, .3);
  position: absolute;
}

.block_2 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Попробовал второму элементу тоже position: absolute добавить?

Comment: проблема в схлопывании маргинов

Comment: @Grundy для абсолютно позиционированных элементов схлопывание не работает

Comment: Почему ты так думаешь? :)

Answer (score 3):

В случае, если у абсолютно позиционированного элемента не указаны свойства `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` - его позиция остается такой же как если бы было указано `position:static`.

В данном случае: свойства не указаны, поэтому позиция в верхнем углу тега `body`.

---

Проблема в вопросе заключается в том, что вертикальные margin могут схлопываться, что и происходит в данном случае.

То есть, отступ для элемента `block_2` схлопывается с отступом `body` и вниз сдвигается сам элемент `body`, и, как следствие, абсолютно позиционированный элемент без заданной позиции.

Поэтому для решения достаточно задать координаты, например `top:0`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(4, 127, 214, .3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.block_2 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```

Comment: Хм... интересно. А как же тогда быть вот с этим утверждением? _"Схлопывание margin не срабатывает: 1) для элементов с абсолютным позиционированием, т. е. таких, у которых position установлено как absolute или fixed..."_   [Источник](https://webref.ru/course/block-model/margin-collapse)

Comment: Или же как вы написали до добавления `top, bottom, left, right`  даже с `position:absolute` элемент фактически не будет считаться абсолютно позиционированным, и соответственно, к нему будет применяться схлопывание (как к НЕабсолютно поз. элементу). Так получается?

Comment: @Eva, а что не так с этим утверждением? В ответе указано маргины каких элементов схлопываются. Среди них нет элементов с абсолютным позиционированием. Плохая ссылка, не расставлены якоря. Посмотри пример в разделе _Вложенные элементы_

Comment: _элемент фактически не будет считаться абсолютно позиционированным, и соответственно, к нему будет применяться схлопывание (как к НЕабсолютно поз. элементу). Так получается?_ - конечно нет.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо просто добавить **position: absolute;**  ко второму блоку тоже

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(4, 127, 214, .3);
  position: absolute;
}

.block_2 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```